# Retornar Json em Array em vez de objeto

Tags: php

Tenho uma api que retorna os dados de 1 usuário, porem ele retorna um objeto:

```
[{"id":"0","nome":"xx","sobrenome":"xx","email":"x","senha":"xxx","unidadexlocal":"Praia da Costa","unidadecurricular":"2","diapreparacao":"1","liberadoexercicio":"0"}]
```

Porem como é apenas um usuario, queria retornar diretamente o array:

```
{"id":"0","nome":"xx","sobrenome":"xx","email":"x","senha":"xxx","unidadexlocal":"Praia da Costa","unidadecurricular":"2","diapreparacao":"1","liberadoexercicio":"0"}
```

Pois assim eu não preciso tratar isso como lista no android, atualmente estou  tendo que fazer assim:  `user.get(0).setnome` quero fazer assim: `user.setnome`

Rota com slimframwork no php:

```
    $app->get('/aluno',function(Request $request,Response $response){
    $usermail = $request->getHeader('PHP_AUTH_USER');
    $senha = $request->getHeader('PHP_AUTH_PW');

    $sql = new Sql();
    $user =  new Usuario();
    $autenticado = $user->login($usermail[0],$senha[0]);

    if ($autenticado) {
        $resultado = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_alunos WHERE email = :EMAIL LIMIT 1",array(
            ":EMAIL"=>$usermail[0]
        ));
        $response = json_encode($resultado);
        return $response;
    }else{
        return $response->withStatus(401);
    }
});
```

Comment: vc faz a consulta com o PDO? usa o `fetch()` ou `fetchAll()` ?

Comment: Sim, com pdo, usando FetchALL()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não é possível alterar o método `select()` para retornar um array sem o índice zero isso acontece quando se o método `fetchAll()` é usado, a solução é troca-lo por `fetch()`

Outra forma é através da função [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) que remove e extrair o primeiro elemento do array passado.

Opcionalmente se estiver usando o php5.6 pode usar o operador `...` para desempacotar o índice zero direto em [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
echo json_encode(...$arr);
```

Saida:

```
{"id":1,"name":"fulano","email":"fulano@abc.com"}
```

**[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/uJmkJ8)**

Digamos que o array retornar por `select()` seja:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => fulano
            [email] => fulano@abc.com
        )

)
```

Exemplo com `array_shift()`

```
$extraido = array_shift($arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($extraido);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => fulano
    [email] => fulano@abc.com
)
```

Comment: Funcionou obrigado, tem muito "metodo" desses que não conheço